# how can i execute my own code after default event happened?

Tags: javascript, jquery

is there a function which we can execute some code after default event happened?
for example, i want to get the scrollTop value after default mouse wheel happened.
can jquery or javascript do this for me?

Comment: Do you want to get the `scrollTop` after mousewheel or after it was actually scrolled? mousewheel is not the only way to scroll

Answer (score 2):

There is a broad range of event handlers in jQuery. You can use `.scroll()` to respond to scroll event. [Full list of events [handlers]](http://api.jquery.com/category/events/).

```
$(window).scroll(function() {
  alert('scrolled!');
});
```

[`scroll()`](http://api.jquery.com/scroll/):

> A scroll event is sent whenever the element's scroll position changes,
>   regardless of the cause. A mouse click or drag on the scroll bar,
>   dragging inside the element, pressing the arrow keys, or using the
>   mouse's scroll wheel could cause this event.

Comment: how can i disable this .scroll() function?

Comment: What do you mean by disable? Prevent default event?

Comment: @Dorsey You want to stop a users mouse from scrolling?

Comment: If you want to unbind event handler then you can use `.off` or `.unbind` functions.

Answer (score 1):

```
​$(document)​.on('mousewheel DOMMouseScroll', function() {
    var top = $(this).scrollTop();
    console.log(top);
})​;​
```

[FIDDLE](http://jsfiddle.net/98Mse/1/)

Comment: Thanks @Esailija, was just about to add that for FF !

Answer (score 1):

Mousewheel handling can be a bit of a pain. You should probably try using a jQuery Mousewheel Plugin.

[This one](http://brandonaaron.net/code/mousewheel/demos) by Brandon Aaron has worked well for me in the past.

Answer (score 0):

I'm using Brandon Aaron's jquery.mousewheel.js to attach events like this:

```
$('#mydiv').mousewheel(function(event, delta, deltaX, deltaY) { alert(deltaY); });
```

you can download it from https://github.com/brandonaaron/jquery-mousewheel/downloads